# email as a foreign key in larave

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-9

Can I make email as a foreign key ?             `$table->foreignId('email')->constrained('users')->onDelete('CASCADE');` . I wrote a seeder and is for an integer value for emai. I need to make email unique

This is my users table

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your `users` table migration?

Comment: Yes but you’ll need to declare it explicitly instead of using “foreignId”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an Foreign Key association with `email` column of `users` table, you cannot use `foreignId` method as it creates **unsignedBigInteger** equivalent column.

You can create the foreign key association as

```php
//Some other table - for eg lets say posts
Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->string('author_email');

    $table->foreign('author_email') // a column on posts table
        ->references('email') //name of the column on users (referenced) table
        ->on('users')    //name of the referenced table 
        ->onDelete('cascade'); //constrain
});
```

Then using this foreign key association you can define the author relation in **Post** model linking it to the **User** model

```php
//Post.php - eloquent model class
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_email', 'email');
}
```

Note: For this to work as expected, `email` column on `users` table must contain unique values i.e have a **unique** index (as you have in the migration of users table)

[Laravel Docs - Migrations - Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: Key column 'email' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table  I get this message and email is not a unsignedBigInetegr right? It is a string ? @Donkarnash

Comment: @nabinakhadka Have updated answer to give more context.